# Is it possible to move Files under Activities to Opportunities/Accounts

Tags: lightning, attachment, files

As Salesforce Files of Archived Activities are not displaying in Lightning, our Sales manager is asked to try an option. That is to move the Files attached to Task/Events to its associated Opportunity or Account after a year or certain time period. I was thinking if we can update the Parent ID of Content Document to ID of Oppr/Acc. But am facing some issues trying that. So is that even possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a [contentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocumentLink.htm) record. As files can be connected to multiple records, you can simply insert this and the file will be connected to both.  This assumes you are using file and not attachment.

Comment: Thats great, it did worked!! But in the Content Document object, ParentID is blank so we really can't find it's associated Opportunity/Account's ID. Is there a way to find it's Parent ID?

Comment: ParentId is the library, per the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm).  Since a file can be connected to N records there is no one parent.  On contentVersion there is a field for firstPublishedLocationId.  And on contentDocument there is latestPublishedVersionId.  So those two fields may be helpful for you in finding the original parent.

Comment: firstPublishedLocationId is not populated on all records and not holding the Parent ID am looking for.  But thank you very much for all your suggestions.